# Is it possible to access to a pickle file saved in a directory in Django views?

Tags: python, django, pickle

Let me explain, here is my problem:
In order not to get bothered with a database, I saved two machine learning models in .pickle in a folder in my Django project.
Then in the corresponding views.py I want to open and use this model.
The fact is that all this works well when I run the server locally but once deployed on heroku, impossible to access these models and the site does not work.

Do you have an idea, is it possible to use this method once deployed or do I have to save them in a database

project files organization :

```
 main_folder >
       models_folder >
              saved_models_folder >
                     my_model.pickle (here the model that I want to open)

       app_folder >
              views.py  ( here is the file in which I try to open the .pickle model)
```

Actually I have this code, but it can't work because I'm not in the models folder when I try to open it.

```
    def open_model(file_name):
        base_dir = 'models_folder\\saved_models_folder'
        file_path = os.path.join(base_dir, file_name)
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            print("Loading Trained Model")
            model = pickle.load(open(file_path, "rb"))

       else:
          print('No model with this name, check this and retry')
          model = None
       return model
```

If someone has a little idea I am greatly interested.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly it is, but as you noticed, you need to be mindful of the directories you're in.

Modern [Django default settings come with a `BASE_DIR`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/conf/project_template/project_name/settings.py-tpl#L15-L16) `Path` object which you can use:

```
from django.conf import settings

def open_model(file_name):
    models_folder = settings.BASE_DIR / 'models_folder' / 'saved_models_folder'
    file_path = os.path.join(models_folder, os.path.basename(file_name))
    # ...
```

Note I added `os.path.basename()` to wrap `file_name` to avoid directory traversal attacks (e.g. someone passing in `../../../secret_file` as the filename).

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I'll use that.